# How do you best create subsums/subtotals

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table with 3 columns, **nr** (INT (10) **name** (varchar (100) and **value** (INT (10)

```
id   name  value
1    aa    10
2    aa    88 
3    bb    20
4    bb    33
5    aa    74
6    bb    66
```

What I want to do is a temporary table or a view that is practically the subsums/subtotals based of the name like this:

```
id   name  value
1    aa    172
2    bb    66
```

I am able to make this using PHP in a very laborious way with a big loop and some small loops but my table has 18000 entries and it is not working this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by the `name`:

```sql
SELECT   name, SUM(value)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comment, you can create a view from this query using the `create view` syntax:

```sql
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT   name, SUM(value)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Alternatively, you can create a table from it using the `create table` syntax:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sum_table 
SELECT   name, SUM(value)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: but how do I transfer this result to a table or a view ? I need the result in a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SELECT INTO

SELECT name, SUM(value) INTO new_table FROM mytable GROUP BY name; GO

Comment: MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing.

Comment: In that case we can use the above create table along with the select query